# what happens when weghts in perceptron algorithm is first initialized with some random values which is very distant from the correct values?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

take this example of a small dataset
[image: this data set is from a homework problem from https://openlearninglibrary.mit.edu/courses/course-v1:MITx+6.036+1T2019/courseware/Week2/week2_homework/?activate_block_id=block-v1%3AMITx%2B6.036%2B1T2019%2Btype%40sequential%2Bblock%40week2_homework]

so here there was a question that instead of initializing weight vector as zeroes what if we initialize to  [1000 , -1000] (there is no offset i.e classifiers passing through origin). will the mistakes that the perceptron algorithm makes increases or decreases as it gets converged?
**Answer : It would significantly increase the number of mistakes.**

Intuition that I have:
the learning rate parameter affects only the scale of the weight vector, not the direction. so even if we take thetha = [1000, -1000] we cannot determine whether it makes less mistakes than [0,0] or not.